# Jersey project Swagger-UI doesn't send @HeaderParam while @PathParam is sent

Tags: java, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui

Java Jersey project using following Swagger Core:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

the document link goes to "openapi.json". Swagger-UI dist ver 3.20.5 is downloaded from [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist). Java code is like this:

```
@Path("/auth")
public class TestConttroller {
    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response testGet(
                @DefaultValue("") @HeaderParam("Authorization") String a,
                @DefaultValue("") @PathParam("id") String id) 
    {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

When sending request from Postman everything works. But when from following Swagger-UI, the header-param string "a" is an empty string while the path-param string is good. The part in openapi.json is here:

```
  "paths" : {
    "/auth/{id}" : {
      "get" : {
        "operationId" : "testGet",
        "parameters" : [ {
          "name" : "Authorization",
          "in" : "header",
          "schema" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "default" : ""
          }
        }, {
          "name" : "id",
          "in" : "path",
          "required" : true,
          "schema" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "default" : ""
          }
        } ],
        "responses" : {
          "default" : {
            "description" : "default response",
            "content" : {
              "application/json" : { },
              "application/xml" : { }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Check with WireShark found the header is not in request at all. Should the problem in Swagger-UI?
[image]

Comment: So you're saying that the request actually enters the `getTest()` method, and the Authorization header is null?

Comment: Exactly. I set break point in the getTest() and checked both parameters. And Wireshark shows that the header was not in the request.

Answer (score 0):

@HeaderParam("Authorization") is like a keyword of HTTP? when I used other name like "Auth" then it works.