# Add field for bearer token to generated Swagger UI in Java EE / Jersey

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, jwt, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a **Java EE 8** application in which I use **OpenAPI** annotations to define my **REST endpoints** and to automatically generate a **Swagger UI**. For authentication I use **JSON Web Tokens (JWT)**.

Everything works fine when I send my requests from Postman, however, I cannot figure out how to have a field for the bearer token added to my Swagger UI.

---

I am definining my security scheme with the `@SecurityScheme` annotation:

```
@SecurityScheme(
        securitySchemeName = "JWT",
        description = "JWT authentication with bearer token",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
        scheme = "bearer",
        bearerFormat = "Bearer [token]"
)
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

}
```

I have tried adding this scheme as a `@SecurityRequirement` both to the `@OpenAPIDefinition` annotation of my resource and directly to my methods.

```
@Path("/items")
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        info = @Info(title = "Items resource", version = "v1"),
        security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "JWT")
)
@Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Interceptors({RolesAllowedInterceptor.class})
@SecurityScheme(
        securitySchemeName = "JWT",
        description = "JWT authentication with bearer token",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
        scheme = "bearer",
        bearerFormat = "Bearer [token]"
)
public class ItemsResource {

    (...)

    @GET
    @Operation(description = "Returns the item list overview")
    @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Valid response")
    @APIResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Authentication required")
    @APIResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Unexpected exception")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @SecurityRequirement(name ="JWT", scopes = "write: read")
    @RolesAllowed({Constants.USER_ROLE_EXPERT})
    public Response getItemListOverview() throws TechnicalException {
        ItemListOverviewVO itemListOverviewVO = logic.getItemListOverview();
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(itemListOverviewVO).build();
    }
```

So I now have `security` information in my OpenAPI JSON file, but still there is no field for the Authorization parameter in the UI.

---

I also found out that there used to be an `@ApiImplicitParameter` annotation in the old Swagger API (see [Swagger UI passing authentication token to API call in header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435286/swagger-ui-passing-authentication-token-to-api-call-in-header/33672270)), but it seems that it was removed from the OpenAPI.

So I tried to use `@HeaderParam` instead (see [Jersey project Swagger-UI doesn't send @HeaderParam while @PathParam is sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209553/jersey-project-swagger-ui-doesnt-send-headerparam-while-pathparam-is-sent)):

```
public Response getItemListOverview(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String bearerToken) throws TechnicalException {
```

Now there is an *Authorization* field in my UI, but when I test the endpoints the requests have no Authorization header. I cannot see it in the network analysis of my browser.

---

The [OpenAPI documentation](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-open-api/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/microprofile-openapi-spec.adoc#quick-overview-of-annotations) has been of little help so far. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to embed the `@SecurityScheme` annotation in `@Components()` and pass that as a parameter to the `@OpenAPIDefinition` annotation:

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        info = @Info(title = "My application", version = "1.0.0"),
        servers = {@Server(url = "/myapp", description = "localhost") },
        security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "JWT"),
        components = @Components(securitySchemes = @SecurityScheme(
                securitySchemeName = "JWT",
                description = "JWT authentication with bearer token",
                type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
                scheme = "bearer",
                bearerFormat = "Bearer [token]"))
)
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

}
```

Comment: I dont get access to this Components. Can you please tell us which pakage has this annoation? Or may be link to a javadoc?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with Java in a while and don't remember any details. However, I mentioned the technologies I was using in my original post. `@OpenAPIDefinition` seems to be part of SwaggerUI, namely the package `swagger-annotations`. It was easy to find by Google search.

Answer (score 0):

May be things has chnaged a bit with the releases. I will just put here what worked for me:

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "Example API", version = "v1"))
@SecuritySchemes(@SecurityScheme(
    name = "JWT",
    description = "JWT authentication with bearer token",
    type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
    scheme = "bearer",
    bearerFormat = "Bearer [token]"))
public interface ExampleResource {
    @DELETE
    @Path("/example")
    @Operation(summary = "Example Summary", tags = "Example Tag",security = 
    @SecurityRequirement(name = "JWT"))
    Response exampleMethod();
}
```

Relevant imports:

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.ParameterIn;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.SecuritySchemeType;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityRequirement;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityScheme;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecuritySchemes;
```